# How to use Manipulate on a function

Tags: manipulate

I would like to use Manipulate on the below function so I can vary the vertex and edge counts on the generated graph. Any help on how to do so would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

```
randomDAG[vertexCount_, edgeCount_] /; 
  edgeCount < vertexCount (vertexCount - 1)/2 := 
 Module[{elems, adjacencyMatrix}, 
  elems = 
   RandomSample@
    PadRight[ConstantArray[1, edgeCount], 
     vertexCount (vertexCount - 1)/2];
  adjacencyMatrix = 
   Take[FoldList[RotateLeft, elems, Range[0, vertexCount - 2]], All, 
     vertexCount]~LowerTriangularize~-1;
  AdjacencyGraph[adjacencyMatrix]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{elems, adjacencyMatrix}, 
  elems = 
   RandomSample@
    PadRight[ConstantArray[1, edgeCount], 
     vertexCount (vertexCount - 1)/2];
  adjacencyMatrix = 
   Take[FoldList[RotateLeft, elems, Range[0, vertexCount - 2]], All, 
     vertexCount]~LowerTriangularize~-1;
  Column[{
    If[adjM, TableForm[adjacencyMatrix,
      TableHeadings -> Automatic], Nothing],
    AdjacencyGraph[adjacencyMatrix,
     VertexLabels -> If[labels, "Name", None],
     ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 {{vertexCount, 10, "Vertex Count"}, 3, 20, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{edgeCount, 15, "Edge Count"}, 
  1, (vertexCount - 2)*(vertexCount + 1)/2, 1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Row[{
   Control[{{labels, True, "Vertex Labels"}, {True, False}}],
   Spacer[25],
   Control[{{adjM, False, "Adjacency Matrix"}, {True, False}}]}]]
```

[image]